# How to call method from same class?

Tags: java

i am using this code to call the method which is present in same class. when i am trying to call the method, i am getting this error..
How to resolve this error

please help me

error:

```
        : cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getRowCount()
```

code:

```
int modelvalue =(int) getRowCount();
System.out.println("This is model"+modelvalue);
```

method:

```
   public int getRowCount() 
   {
      return dataz.size();
   }
```

Comment: Please show your class.

Comment: The method itself is of no use; what is needed is the class code.

Comment: Where are you calling that `getRowCount()` method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably calling the method from a *static* method (`main`?).

When you have *non-static* method, you have to access it through an object.

You should do:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass(); //Actually it's your class
int modelvalue = myObj.getRowCount();
```

Another note, it's redundant to cast the result to `int`. It's already an `int`.

Comment: What if the call to this method from another non static method ?

Comment: You are guessing that he is invoking from a main/static method :-)

Comment: @MarounMaroun :P , I upvote it because I think this is very probable  reason .

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thanks for Answer.. the method was in another class....i realized after you answered....

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `getRowCount()` in static method then you will get this error.You need to create object of the class containg method and call the method on that object.
eg :

```
public class Abc
{
  public int getRowCount() 
   {
      return dataz.size();
   }

public static void main(String args[])
{
Abc ob=new Abc();
int modelvalue =ob.getRowCount();
System.out.println("This is model"+modelvalue);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Because you called the method with a missing definition where it is defined ,since you have not shown your class structure on how you define your method and how your going to access it ...but this is similar issue caused when you have'n instantiated the class it belongs like

```
 MyTestClass test = new MyTestClass();

 int result = test.getRowCount();

 System.out.println("Result is Integer {0},is:",result);
```